# Custom code execution in EF migrations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration

Working with the Entity Frameworks migrations successfully in our project.
But now I run into a special case where I need to update a table in need of some business logic (located in our application as C# code). So I tried to spawn a thread in the migrations `Up` method and doing this table update with the business logic.
This table update is not required for the application execution and should be occur in the background.

I am doing this somewhat like this:

```
public partial class MyMigration : DbMigration
{
  public override void Up()
  {
     // ... do some sql migration here ...

     // after executing the sql migrations custommethod should run
     // migration seems to wait until CustomMethod finished work
     new Thread(() => ExecuteCustomMethodDatabaseContext()).Start();
  }
}
```

I would expect that the `Up` method returns after starting the thread and EF sets the migration in the MigrationHistory to done. Thus the app can start and somewhere in the background the table gets updated.

But not so, the migrations seems to run while the thread runs (this takes a LOT of time).

So my according questions:

1. Is it good practise in general to execute custom code in
   DBmigrations?
2. If not, how can I accomplish the need of custom code execution in my
       case? (without rewriting the business logic in a stored procedure or
       somewhat)
3. If yes, what I am doing wrong? How can I execute this code within an migration and without blocking it?

Comment: Why does it have to be integrated with migrations? Can't you do your asynchronous action somewhere later in the startup process of your app?

Comment: Cause the execution is only required one-time after the latest sql migration (updated the code block) and not every time the app starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Up and Down methods on DbMigration merely build up an in-memory model that later gets translated to SQL. You have two options for executing custom logic:

1. Perform your logic on the database server using T-SQL by using the Sql method.
2. Perform logic in the Seed method of your migrations configuration class (typically Migrations\Configuration.cs). This gets called after all of the migrations have been applied during Update-Database

Comment: Seed method looks very promising since its not exactly what I want. In my understanding the Seed method runs after EVERY migration. But I want this code only run once when a special migration was executed. If I add other migrations later and the special one was already migrated I don't want the custom code to run again. Is there a way to do this within the Seed method?

Comment: @dasheddot What does your custom logic do? If it creates database artifacts, you can check to see if they exist before running.

Comment: I am trying to refill a table with data built by business logic. It would be tricky to check if the data is already refreshed or not. But it's a good hint anyway

Comment: So finally your first sentence in your answer was the solution already. I found out that the reason why the thread hangs was simply cause of the fact that the migration model gets built in the up method but gets executed later. Cause of active sql transactions set by the migration, the thread blocks when he comes to the custom savechanges method. So my solution was to extract the thread into a seperate migration with the same hash so there were no influences by other sql queries. So I got it to work as I intended initially. Still don't know whats best practices to solve such scenarios..

Comment: Anyone have any answers for this? Performing migration logic in C# would be wildly useful and be able to be able to handle complex migration logic (ie: serializing something to a changed JSON structure for example, or performing logic across fields/entities). The only solution we have for this right now is to run a separate console app that reads in the data, performs the transformation, and writes it. And we need to make sure to run this only once right after the specific migration is run. Very ugly / error prone.